# Insertar filas nuevas a través de Conexión a un txt (Excel 2013)

Tags: excel

Tengo un Excel (2013) con una conexión a un txt. Cada vez que lo abro el data range se refresca con la información más reciente pero, en vez de sobreescribir sobre las filas anteriores, necesito que los datos antiguos se muevan para conservarlos junto a los nuevos.

He probado a seleccionar tanto la opción "Insert entire rows for new data, clear unused cells" como "Insert cells for new data, delete unused cells", pero no consigo mi objetivo, en ambos casos los nuevos datos sobreescriben los viejos.

¿Alguna pista para solucionarlo?

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: A ser posible, preferiría una solución que no implicase el uso de una macro, ya que nunca las he usado y me costaría un poco adaptarme. Quiero pensar que la opción que busco está entre las listadas en las propiedades de la conexión pero que no estoy haciendo algo bien...

Answer (score 0):

si la conexión al `.txt` la haces a través de una macro deberías hacer un algoritmo de comparación verificando si los datos ya ingresados son iguales a los del .txt, en caso de que no lo sean agregarías los nuevos datos. No se como serán esos datos ni el formato de la tabla pero en principio se me ocurre algo así

```
Sub agregardato()
'suponiendo que el .txt contiene datos disintos a los ultimos cargados y la informacion del mismo se hace en una sola fila
'insertamos una nueva fila desplazando hacia abajo los antiguos registros
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
'pegas la informacion de tu .txt en la nueva fila creada
End Sub
```

Espero solucionar tu problema, en caso de que este no haya sido resuelto por favor comunicalo con algunos ejemplos mas claros. Buena suerte!